# How to connect a cookie?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to connect cookies.
I have this js. It is difficult to combine the check list `<ul>` and to plug cookies.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var arrow = $('.multi-accordion li > a').next();
            if (arrow.length) {
            $(arrow).parent().append('<img src="v.svg" alt="">');
            }
    $('.multi-accordion li > a').on('click', function (event) {
        var value = $('.multi-accordion li > a').index(this);
            Mage.Cookies.set('nav-item', value);
        var $this = $(this), $next = $this.next();
            if ($next.length) {
            $next.slideToggle().parent().toggleClass('opened').siblings().children('ul').filter(':visible').slideToggle();
            event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Sylon/no120eqp/9/)
I have this js function for cms Magento.

```
Mage.Cookies.set('name', 'value'); // install cookie
Mage.Cookies.get('name'); // get cookie
Mage.Cookies.clear('name'); // remove cookie
```

Comment: I see no cookie code in your code

Comment: I had a lot of attempts. But they did not work either accordion or cookies.

Comment: Are you trying to save the state of accordian in a cookie?

Comment: FYI `$(arrow)` is redundant; it's already jQueryfied since it came from a `$` selector. You can call `.parent()` on it directly.

Comment: @Aerovistae I have a dynamic html markup. So I need to use. $(arrow) How should I write to check your words?

Answer (score 1):

No need to include cookie.js. 
You can save nav-item index in session storage.
Visit below link for session storage.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    // CHECK IF nav-item IS STORED IN SESSION STORAGE
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("nav-item"))
    {
        $('#nav > li > a:eq(' + sessionStorage.getItem("nav-item") + ')').next().show();
    }
    $('#nav > li > a').click(function () {
        var intNavIndex = $(this).index(this);
        // SAVE NAV INDEX TO SESSION STROAGE
        sessionStorage.setItem("nav-item", intNavIndex);
        $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
        if ($(this).next().is(":visible")) {
            $(this).next().slideUp();
        } else {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        }
        $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Only this will not work accordion. I need to work this condition `$('.multi-accordion li > a').on('click', function (event) {`...`event.preventDefault();` Please help, use your version of my script.

Comment: I would like to suggest you that please create a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/).
So I can assist you properly

Answer (score 1):

You dosen't need connect cookie.js Magento already has a js methods for work with cookie.

**As example**:

`Mage.Cookies.set('name', 'value'); 
 Mage.Cookies.get('name');
 Mage.Cookies.clear('name');`

Also you can use [this](https://github.com/evgv/acm) js lib (without jQuery)